# ConstraintLayout to build responsive app

Tags: android

i'm working on an android app , trying to make it responsive in different screen sizes, so i'm using constraintlayout . But i had a problem when i test it in  a tablet in mode portrait (vertical) there is so much space in the bottem i've tried to work with PercentRelativeLayout(supports percentage based margin and dimensions for Views) it has a good result but it's deprecated. Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ConstraintLayout Chaining to connect your Views into a group and then you can center, expand, pack these into the available space as desired. This layout will change dynamically based on the screen size and orientation.

Using alternate layouts as mentioned (layout-sw600dp) is also a good idea. The system will automatically use this layout instead of the default layout. 600dp is a good display width to make the breakpoint for tablets.

Comment: Thanks for your help  Mike :D

Comment: Here is a good guide for Chaining and ConstraintLayout that helped me: https://medium.com/google-developers/building-interfaces-with-constraintlayout-3958fa38a9f7

Comment: Thanks Mike i really appreciate your help :D